# .net Switch statement and random number: Not all code paths return a value. Must I include a default?

Tags: c#, .net, random, switch-statement

Heres a tiny function to randomly return either +1 or -1

```
public static int PlusOrMinus()
{
    int chance = MyRandom.Random.Next(0, 2);

    switch (chance)
    {
        case 0:
            return -1;

        case 1:
            return 1;
    }               
}
```

Compiler is telling me not all code paths return a value. As far as I'm concerned its *impossible* for chance not to be either 0 or 1.

Must you always include a default case for a switch statement like this to compile?

Comment: Compiler doesn't know that it's impossible though! You always need a default.

Comment: @Rikalous you don't need a default, the return statement could be outside of the switch.

Comment: Of course that could be replaced with `return MyRandom.Random.Next(0,2) == 0 : ? -1 : 1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not run your code. The compiler therefore has no way of knowing that the integer defined will never fall out of the range 0-1.

Therefore, yes, you must supply a default or a `return` outside of the `switch`.

Answer (score 8):

This might be a little simpler:

```
return chance == 0 ? -1: 1;
```

Comment: what is that question mark thing called? Thats new to me, I want to read up on it

Comment: Its a ternary operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Why not generate 0 or 1, and then just turn 0 into -1?

```
var x = MyRandom.Random.Next(0, 2);
if (x == 0)
    return -1;
return x;
```

Or more concise:

```
return MyRandom.Random.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

---

**UPDATE:** And to answer your question, no you don't *have* to include the `default`, you can also do something like this:

```
public static int PlusOrMinus()
{
    int chance = MyRandom.Random.Next(0, 2);

    switch (chance)
    {
        case 0:
            return -1;

        case 1:
            return 1;
    }               

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unreachable code.");
}
```

But in any case, the *compiler* must be satisfied that all execution paths either return a value or throw an exception, regardless of whether *you* know that some of these paths will never actually execute.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot guess what you've done above.  Really you could do with refactoring your code to be cleaner and safer.  Something like

```
public static int PlusOrMinus()
{
    int chance = MyRandom.Random.Next(0, 2);

    return chance == 0 ? -1 : 1;
}
```